# Subquery returns more than 1 value: DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-update

I am trying to adjusted multiple rows for daylight savings time in a single table. I need to add an hour to any records that were written before I caught the error. I am getting the error

```
Subquery returns more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, != etc
```

I understand what it is telling me, I just can't think of a way around it. This is what I am trying to do:

```
UPDATE Table
SET LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime + '1:00:00'
WHERE (DateWritten > '3/10/13') AND (DateWritten < '3/11/13 7:00:00') AND (varCharColumn <> 'aString')
```

I have also tried the variation and received the same error.

```
UPDATE Table
SET LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime + '1:00:00'
WHERE DateWritten IN (SELECT DateWritten FROM Table WHERE (same clause as above))
```

Comment: You're getting a subquery error on the first statement? There's not even a subquery in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely have a trigger on that table that was written in a way that it cannot handle multirow updates. If that is the case, either fix the trigger, or use a cursor for the update.

Also, as others have mentioned, you cannot use the `+` operator for time calculations. Use `DATEADD` instead.

---

Just to clarify: Your UPDATE cannot cause the error you are getting. The most likely cause is a trigger that was put in place by someone else. You can see Triggers in SSMS under the table itself. See if you have a trigger there and post the code if you do. Maybe we can help fix it.

If you don't want to mess with the trigger for now, use a cursor like this:

```
DECLARE complex_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT LocalDateTime
    FROM dbo.Table
    WHERE (DateWritten > '3/10/13') AND (DateWritten < '3/11/13 7:00:00') AND (varCharColumn <> 'aString') ;
OPEN complex_cursor;
FETCH FROM complex_cursor;
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.Table
  SET LocalDateTime = DATEADD(hour,1,LocalDateTime) 
  WHERE CURRENT OF complex_cursor;

  FETCH FROM complex_cursor;
END
CLOSE complex_cursor;
DEALLOCATE complex_cursor;
GO
```

Source [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) (with adjustments).

This should solve your immediate problem. Keep in mind however:

1. You really should fix the trigger as it might cause other problems.
2. Be careful with cursors. I general they are a a performance nightmare. I the case of a one-off update like yours they are however acceptable.

Comment: This scenario seems more likely because it would better explain the subquery error on the first statement.

Comment: I believe you're 100% correct about the trigger, but I want to reiterate for you like I have others, the adding the `1:00:00` is **not** invalid syntax. This statement `SELECT CAST('1/1/2013 3:00 PM' AS DATETIME) + '1:00:00'` will in fact return `16:00` hours.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, you are correct that the `+` will not throw an error. However, it does not yield the functionality the OP was looking for either. So while maybe a little unclear, my statement is still correct. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't yield the functionality the OP was looking for? The OP is looking to add one hour to the time. As I stated - it does just that.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud you're adding the CAST as if it's necessary. The OP never mentions CAST, so I fail to see how you're helping using CAST in all your comments. See this SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23f9b3/1

Comment: Consider the fact that the OP's field is a date and time. I'm adding a CAST because I needed the original operator to be a date and time.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud where does he say it's a date and time? It's a datetime field from all indications

Comment: Oh, and the SQL Fiddle works by the way, so that only proves that the syntax is valid. The second column is in fact 1 hour greater than the first selected column.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud that's my point. The `CAST` is NOT necessary. Glad you understand now.

Comment: @MattBusche, ***in my example*** it's necessary. I was providing a mock example of a datetime value on the left hand side of the operation. What is so difficult to understand about that? And why would you build a SQL Fiddle to only further my point that the syntax is in fact valid?

Comment: In addition to being a SQL noob, I am also a StackOverflow noob, so thought I would just put my response in here as well. 

My query works exactly as I wrote it when only updating a single record. Replacing with DateAdd still resulted in it not liking updating multiple records. I am not familiar with triggers, or anything other than basic CRUD so I may just update everything manually. Its only about 300 records. 

Thank you for your quick responses, and I will continue to work on leveling up my SQL skills.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud the SQL Fiddle shows that a CAST IS NOT NECESSARY. Have a nice day.

Comment: @WChambers, I just added a little more info to my answer, based on your last comment.

Comment: @SebastianMeine this is getting very close to what I want to do, and thank you for your input. When I run the updated query, it is adjusting the first record in my range.  So it's as if I need a FETCH NEXT type of statement. I am not familiar with SQL loops, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: @WChambers - yes, you are correct, you need to loop while there are rows coming from the cursor. Sorry I missed that the example didn't have that part. I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateAdd()`

```
UPDATE Table
SET LocalDateTime = DateAdd(hour,1,LocalDateTime)
WHERE DateWritten > '3/10/13'
AND DateWritten < '3/11/13 7:00:00' 
AND varCharColumn <> 'aString'
```

Alternatively you can also use `BETWEEN` for a comparison on your DateWritten column

```
UPDATE Table
SET LocalDateTime = DateAdd(hour,1,LocalDateTime)
WHERE DateWritten BETWEEN '3/10/13'AND '3/11/13 7:00:00' 
AND varCharColumn <> 'aString'
```

Based off of [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/98ef9dc8-5553-4684-81c2-7c9132103473/), it looks like your `Table` may be used in a view which could be preventing updating of multiple records.

[DateAdd documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: This isn't really going to change the outcome for the OP if they are getting the subquery error on the first statement - all you did here was fix up the fact that the OP needs to use `DateAdd`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud doesn't change the fact that using + 1 hour is not the best choice of syntax. If he tries this and it doesn't work then we can look at other issues.

Comment: I agree the OP needs to use `DateAdd` but the ` + '1:00:00' ` is ***not*** invalid syntax. This statement `SELECT CAST('1/1/2013 3:00 PM' AS DATETIME) + '1:00:00'` will return `16:00` hours.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I missed where he was casting dates in his query. You win.

Comment: Thanks for all of the input everyone. To be honest, I am not super familiar with SQL, so I may just end up changing them manually. Only about 300 records.

Using my original query with a WHERE ID = anID, I got the expected results.